How should I fix IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable?
I am iterating over a range of N:
for i in range(N):
 angle1 = np.deg2rad(np.random.uniform(0, 10))
 angle2 = np.deg2rad(np.random.uniform(0, 180))
 interchange_indices = np.random.rand(i) < 0.5
 angle1[interchange_indices], angle2[interchange_indices] = angle2[interchange_indices], angle1[interchange_indices]

 kappa = evolve(angle1, angle2, L)

The issue occurred with interchange_indices, where I got IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
I originally had angle1 (angle2 was similar) defined as angle1 = np.deg2rad(np.random.uniform(0, 10, i)), but had issues because of the random sampling with i. Therefore, I used the low, high method instead. However, it created this new issue. What should I do? Thanks in advance.

angle1 and angle2 are just numbers.  interchange_indices is a boolean.  What do you think angle1[interchange_indices] is supposed to do?

Did you mean if interchange_indices: / angle1, angle2 = angle2, angle1?

Full error message, please.  Make sure you understand how the variable came to be a scalar.  And review why you are trying to index it.

But as written, interchange_indices is not a boolean; it's an array of booleans.

It's not explicitly stated, but I'm going to assume that you're trying to do the following:

generate several pairs of angles
in each pair:

the first angle is randomly sampled from a uniform distribution between 0 and 10 degrees
the second is randomly sampled from a uniform distribution between 0 and 180 degrees


for each pair, swap the order of the angles with 50% probability

The index error occurs because as written, angle1 and angle2 are scalars, not arrays. Scalars simply do not support indexing.
import numpy as np
angle1 = np.deg2rad(np.random.uniform(0, 10))
angle1[True]  # IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

If the angles were 0d arrays, they could be indexed by a scalar or 0d array:
angle1 = np.asarray(np.deg2rad(np.random.uniform(0, 10)))
angle1[False]  # array([], dtype=float64)
angle1[np.asarray(True)]  # array([0.03021378])

but then your problem would be that interchange_indices never a scalar or 0d array; it is an array of length i.
for i in range(3):
     interchange_indices = np.random.rand(i) < 0.5
     print(interchange_indices)
# []
# [False]
# [ True  True]

You have two options to resolve the error. If you want to keep the loop, you only need interchange_indices to be a scalar, and you probably want to just use an if statement rather than boolean indexing.
N = 3
for i in range(N):
    angle1 = np.deg2rad(np.random.uniform(0, 10))
    angle2 = np.deg2rad(np.random.uniform(0, 180))
    # interchange_indices = np.random.rand(i) < 0.5
    # there should not be an `i` in the line above
    # that would produce an array of length i, but angle1 and angle2 are scalars
    interchange_indices = np.random.rand() < 0.5
    if interchange_indices:
        angle1, angle2 = angle2, angle1
    print(angle1, angle2, interchange_indices)
# 0.14806055963275674 1.033872399798009 False
# 1.0644875532575504 0.08971188854189044 True
# 0.1720723141790743 0.32268645386711226 False

Alternatively, I don't see what is wrong with your original approach:
angle1 = np.deg2rad(np.random.uniform(0, 10, N))
angle2 = np.deg2rad(np.random.uniform(0, 180, N))
interchange_indices = np.random.rand(N) < 0.5
angle1[interchange_indices], angle2[interchange_indices] = (
    angle2[interchange_indices], angle1[interchange_indices])
angle1, angle2, interchange_indices

It's not stated what evolve is supposed to do. If it only accepts scalars, you might as well use the first approach. If it accepts arrays, go with the second approach.
If I've misunderstood what you are trying to do, try stating it. It is difficult to infer the intent from code that doesn't work.
